# C program to find number of occurrences of substring in string

Tags: c, string, numbers, find, substring

I have a problem with my code so far. I researched the topic on stackoverflow and found solutions but those don't seem to work. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char sentence[1000];
    char word[100];
    int count=0;
    fgets(sentence, 999, stdin);
    fgets(word, 99, stdin);
    int word_len=strlen(word);
    char *p;
    for(p=(char*)sentence; (p=strstr(p, word)); p+=word_len)
    {
        ++count;
    }
    printf("%d", count);
    return 0;
}
```

But it prints out 1 in any case, no matter how many times the word is found in the sentence. Any help?

Comment: remove the newline from the `word`.

Comment: You are wasting 1 byte in each of the char arrays. You can use the whole array size in the call to fgets(): `fgets(sentence, sizeof sentence, stdin);`

Comment: Hmmm ... how many times does "aba" exist in "abababa"? Two or Three?

Comment: You code works, if you remove the newline.

Comment: "*... it prints out 1 in any case*" sure?

Comment: Well, it did, since as people mentioned before I had a newline in my substring, so it would only find the substring once. Thanks to everyone that helped.  @pmg It exists both two and three times, until you run it through the program.

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
....
fgets(word, 99, stdin);
char *p = strchr(word, '\n');
if(p)
    *p = 0;
int word_len=strlen(word);
for(p=sentence; (p=strstr(p, word)); p+=word_len)
....
```

Comment: It also works if I use scanf %s for the word since I don't need empty spaces in that string. Thanks for the tip!